# Django Application down because of OS update in server

Tags: python, django, internal-server-error

This is my first question on stack overflow so, please help me out.
We have hosted our application in ulcis.com and recently dreamhost server updated from centOS to ubuntu and in result our application is down. We had our application running in virtualenv and now the virtualenv throws error when i try to validate my application.

```
`(envnew)[ps#####3]:~/------/------]$ python manage.py validate
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
`
```

Even pip install or uninstall is not working. I believe because of server os upgrade python is getting conflicted in virtualenv. Please help me in sorting this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Create again your environment.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but somehow python is conflicting and the application is not running.

Comment: @prasanna-vijayanplease please type your received error

Comment: You will need to remake your env...it is not finding django. if you cant remove/create new enviroments or run pip the issue is with your python version, maybe there is a conflict. Check your active python version.

Comment: Thanks to all. After remake the application works perfectly.